# Array, Dictionary or List in a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, session, data-structures

What would be the most efficient way of storing a set of values in a session? I'm guessing it's either a List/Array or Dictionary. Basically, when a user selects an item from a DropDownList, a value (`between 1 and N where N <= 20`) is sent back to the server. I'd then like this value to be used as an index (if using arrays) or key (if using a dictionary) within the session. I don't want the value to be seen by the user, hence why it's not stored in the DDL. From what I gather, dictionaries are designed for key-lookups. However, since the scale is quite small, are there any overheads of using a dictionary that could make it less efficient in this case? Each corresponding value is unique to the user, so I've decided to use  sessions.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: how many concurrent users are we talking about? If not 1000's, probably a micro-optimisation...

Comment: @Mitch - Thread safety issues differ between them though, hopefully someone chimes in on that as well

Comment: There are peak times where 1000-2000 are expected concurrently. Usually there are a few hundred on concurrently. Will I have to handle threading issues with this method?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you're trying to do? It's not clear what you mean by "I'd then like this value to be used as an index or key within the session." What are you indexing or hashing? Also what do you mean by, and what is the significance of, "I don't want the value to be seen by the users, hence why it's not stored in the DDL"? Data Definition Language? That would be an RDBMS thing.

Comment: @gWiz:I don't have code access atm. However, it's just a DropDownList where the user selects an item. Each item has a value between 1 and 20. Assuming an array is used, this value becomes the index (myArray[DropDownList_value]). The array holds the IDs of a custom type - ID's which I don't want the user to see (hence why I'm not just putting the ID as the value of each item). By DDL, I meant DropDownList :)

Comment: And why can't you just store the value in `myArray` at `DropDownList_value`?

Comment: @gWiz: Server side, the value is stored in myArray. myArray contains 4 values for UserX, for example. myArray[0] = "UniqueSecretID123", myArray[1] = "AnotherSecretID"etc..  When the user selects an item from the dropdownlist, the corresponding value of that item (0,1,2,3) will be used as the DropDownList_Value in the array. The server then does further processing now that it knows which UniqueID the user wants to access.

Comment: I see, thanks for further explaining. Are the secret ID's stored in a database? And does the user only occasionally change the DropDownList_Value? If both are true, why not just store the currently selected UniqueID value in the session at the time the selection is made? And only when they change it, pull the list of IDs out of the database, find the new one, and store it back into the Session? That way you only do the lookup once-per-selection.

Comment: The ID's are stored in a database, but I need to know what the currently selected UniqueID value is in the first place. The problem is, the user selects the item from the dropdownlist, but what value is posted back to the server so that it knows which UniqueID to pull from the database? I don't want the dropdownlist to return the actual uniqueID to the server as that should be secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays would be best option for you here.

Dictionary could be more scalable if you are intending to add some more custom type with minimal changes in code. Fetching an item from Dictionary is usually a 1 hop operation. But the only overhead involved in using Dictionary is serialization. Serialization will only be involved when you use SQLServer or StateServer to store your sessions.

I did some benchmarking where I used BinaryFormatter to serialize an array of int, List, and a Dictionary.

I serialized each object 100000 time.
Each data-structure contains 20 values.
Here are the results:

```
int[] took 1955 ms to serialize
List<int> took 4135 ms to serialize
Dictionary<int,int> took 27917ms to serialize
```

So be careful when using Dictionary when serialization is involved.

========================================
To support my argument that fetching an item from dictionary is quiet efficient, I also did some benchmarking where I stored 20 items in each data-structure (which I used above) and fetched items for 10000000 times. Here are the results

```
int[] took 136 ms to serialize
List<int> took 184 ms to serialize
Dictionary<int,int> took 877 ms to serialize
```

Sure a little slower then the other two, but it provides more scalability then the other two data-structure.

But if it is a fixed number of items, then go for Arrays. They are the most efficient in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are there any threading issues I should be worried about?

Comment: You would be using session, so you don't have to worry about threads. Sessions providers take care of locking.
But if you are using any global or static variables, then you have to be careful.

Comment: No global variables, and the only static variable is my logging class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a micro-optimization, but the absolute highest performance will most likely come from arrays.  Your best bet is to try all your options and validate empirically.